# How to get sender's WindowsIdentity from recieved msmq message?

Tags: c#, security, msmq, windows-identity

How to get sender's WindowsIdentity from recieved msmq message?

I use msmq as a transport and a Security Appplication Block with Authorization Rule Provider for operation's authorization. I need WindowsPrincipal and not GenericPrincipal because rules granted to active directory user's groups and not to specific users.
Message.SenderId can be converted to SecurityIdentifier but I did not find how to get WindowsIdentity from it.

```
void AuthorizeOperation(Message message)
{
   // get sender windows principal
   WindowsPrincipal principal = ... ???

   // extract operation name from message body
   string operation = ... 

   AuthorizationFactory.GetAuthorizationProvider().Authorize(principal, operation);
}
```

Comment: Note that The SenderId can be easily spoofed in a message so relying on it is weak security.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround but not sure that it is a right solution.
Instead of WindowsPrincipal I create a GenericPrincipal and inject user's authorization groups recieved from active directory.

```
var sid = new SecurityIdentifier(message.SenderId, 0);
var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain), IdentityType.Sid, sid);
var principal = new GenericPrincipal(
                   new GenericIdentity(user.SamAccountName),
                   user.GetAuthorizationGroups().Select(g => g.SamAccountName).ToArray());
bool authorized = AuthorizationFactory.GetAuthorizationProvider().Authorize(principal, operation);
```